# No margins set when exporting jasper report to docx

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using Jaspersoft Studion 6.0.3 in Eclipse Luna and I seem to get a margin problem when exporting to docx (but not odt) ? Should I be setting a config property on export? Essentially if I export this directly from the preview view to docx it works okay, I can print with no warnings but as soon as I export through code (very basic code)

```
JRDocxExporter docxExporter=new JRDocxExporter();     
docxExporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));     
docxExporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(subReportPathName));     
docxExporter.exportReport();
```

it produces margins of 0, 0 , 0 , 0 in the docx and thus a print warning. My margins are currently 20 top, left and right and 38 bottom (this large bottom margin was needed to get it working in preview mode).

Thanks,

Comment: Out of interest to allow more compatibility (as the document is sent outside the organisation)  was asked to change it to a doc (rtf) output and the problem went away...  Not sure this 'solution' will help most people but I thought I'd add it as a comment.